# Countable Union of Sets of Different Dimensions

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$ be fixed. I came across the following object:
$$ \Omega = \bigcup_{N=1}^{\infty} X^{N} $$
where $X^{N}$ stands for the usual $N$-fold cartesian product of $X$ with itself. This seems a very strange object to me, since each $X^{N}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{dN}$, so these are not subsets of the same set. I think the notation might be misleading and this union stands for something else, but I don't know what it could be. I've heard about disjoint (topological) unions, but I don't know if this is the case. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: It looks like a precise way of defining the limit $lim_{N\to\infty} X^N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an arbitrary set $X$, this $\bigcup_{n\ge1}X^n$ is just the set of all (nonempty) *finite sequences*  of elements of $X$.
(In this abstraction these are also called '*words over the alphabet $X$*' e.g. in the theory of semigroups or abstract languages.)

If $X$ is a topological space, then we can naturally equip $\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\ge1}X^n$ with a topology as well, as you suggested, using the product topology and the topological disjoint union.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

To help make sense of $\Omega$, we can think of it as being embedded in $X^\omega$, the set of sequences $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ of elements in $X$. Fix an element $a \in X$. Then we can identify
$$
X^N = \{(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty} \in X^\omega: k > N  \implies x_k = a\}
$$
You can check that, with this identification, $\Omega$ is the set of all sequences $(x_n)_{n = 1}^{\infty} $ of elements in $X$ which are equal to $a$ for all but finitely many terms.

Comment: There is no infinite sequence in that union which is the collection of all finite sequences of elements from X!  Make it clear that you are mearly embedding the union into the set of all infinite sequences.

Comment: I'll make that more clear. To be clear, I don't know that this is the right way to interpret the object in the OP, but I don't see any other way to make sense of it.